# plugins.cordova.io - Helpshift-Plugin on Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, helpshift

PhonegapBuild now supports Plugins from the Cordova Plugin Site (This is sooo great :)!) But i have a problem installing the Helpshift Plugin "com.helpshift.HSPhoneGapPlugin". I always get an Error when pg tries to build the iOS-app... "Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build server".

This only happens when i include this plugin in the config.xml.

Here is the log from the build process: http://tny.cz/b33c494d

Thanks in advance, 
Max

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming across this, as of July 2015 helpshift almost certainly will not work on Phonegap build in its current state.

The reason for this is they are not setting up the SDK correctly with the plugin. As with all cordova/phonegap plugins, the necessary files to make the integration happen need to be copied over in the plugin instructions, however, as per the helpshift docs there are a lot of manual steps that need to be taken in xCode to make the integration take.

I have seen an open source project try and fix this, however building didn't work for me in that either.

The solution right now is as follows: (for iOS)

Use Cordova (yes this means that you can stop reading if you have to use PG build)
Add iOS to your project
Install the Helpshift phonegap plugin using

```
cordova plugin add <path to helpshift plugin>
```

Once complete, jump on over to
https://developers.helpshift.com/ios/getting-started/#automated-integration

and download the helpshift automated integration assistant.

Run through it, installing v4.9.1 (later ones have issues with resources missing)

Jump on in to xCode and run your project, it should build just fine... Now follow the instructions on initialising helpshift in phonegap

https://developers.helpshift.com/phonegap/?_ga=1.99559902.1744288086.1387515146#initializing-helpshift-phonegap-plugin

*** Another point to note, their plugin is single platform only. I have made a copy of it that is doing both Android and iOS but have not yet worked out how to get android to fire with a recent version of Cordova Android. The gradle integration isn't compiling and the guide on their site cant find the SDK. I'll post a link to the multi platform version of the plugin once its all working.

Answer (score 0):

I am Gireesh, product manager at Helpshift. My team tried to reproduce this issue. By looking at the stack trace , one observation that we have is

/project/Selfie/Plugins/com.helpshift.HSPhoneGapPlugin/HelpshiftPG.h:10:9: fatal error: 'Helpshift.h' file not found

This is likely due to below build error

```
CompileC build/Selfie.build/Release-iphoneos/Selfie.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HelpshiftPG.o Selfie/Plugins/com.helpshift.HSPhoneGapPlugin/HelpshiftPG.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

(1 failure)

**Solution**: Can you try to include the files correctly and retry the SDK integration?

Alternatively, we also have automated installation steps for Phonegap. You can find details at the below location

https://developers.helpshift.com/phonegap/?_ga=1.99559902.1744288086.1387515146#add-helpshift-phonegap-plugin

Please let us know how we can help further.

For future use: The fastest way to get a solution for an issue with Helpshift SDK is to write into support@helpshift.com.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I opened a ticket and got a few answers. Gaya** is the support agent... he doesn`t know what PGB is and says i should use the cordova CLI commands... Maybe you can have a look at this. Best regards

Comment: Hi Max - I am taking a look at this and will make sure you get a speedy response on the support channel. Thanks for your patience.